# Bash replacing part of output with a string

Tags: linux, bash

I have this command that gets a certain output; 
command;

```
uptime | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' > temp                    
awk '{ sub(" min","") sub("users", "user");print > "temp" }' ./temp
```

When I do cat temp, the output becomes;

13:24:16 up  1:33,  3 user,  load average: 0.30, 0.56, 0.63

I want to replace 1:33 with this new time I created with this command;

```
awk '{printf("%02d:%02d\n",($1/60/60%24),($1/60%60))}' /proc/uptime > temp2
```

This gets as output;

```
01:33
```

So, in a nutshell, I want to replace 1:33 in the output of the first command with the output of the second command 01:33. I have been googling and trying but I keep failing so I decided to come here. I have found sollutions with sed, awk and grep. But I can't figure out the perfect one for this problem.

Comment: What do you want your output to look like when the system has been up for hours, days, or weeks (etc) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match the string with a regex and substitute with `sed`.

```
echo '13:24:16 up 1:33, 3 user, load average: 0.30, 0.56, 0.63' | 
sed 's/up [^,]*,/up '"$(awk '{printf("%02d:%02d\n",($1/60/60%24),($1/60%60))}' /proc/uptime)"',/'
```

will output (on my system):

```
13:24:16 up 03:58, 3 user, load average: 0.30, 0.56, 0.63
```

Comment: You can probably refactor the Awk script to also subsume the `sed` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to convert human-readable time to `HH:MM:SS`:

```
uptime | awk '
  NR==1 {t = sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $1/3600, $1%3600/60, $1%60); next}
        {split($0, a, "  "); print $1, $2, t, a[2], a[3]}
' /proc/uptime -
```

```
10:24:39 up 00:53:05 1 users, load average: 0.52, 0.58, 0.59
```